# SQL - SQL Server 2019: Group rows with that are less than 14 days apart and return the 1 row of each group

Tags: sql, partition

I have a tablelike this:

If t1_view_dt are within 14 days of each other, I need to show the 1st row of each group in another column named t2_view_dt.

```
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| row number | user | t1_view_dt | t2_view_dt | series |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          1 |  123 |        1/1 |        1/1 | 1      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          2 |  123 |       1/10 |       1/10 | 1      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          3 |  123 |       1/20 |       1/20 | 2      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          4 |  123 |       1/25 |       1/20 | 2      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          5 |  123 |       1/30 |       1/20 | 2      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          6 |  123 |       2/10 |       2/10 | 3      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|          7 |  123 |       2/15 |       2/10 | 3      |
+------------+------+------------+------------+--------+
```

For example, Row number 1 and 2 belong to the same group as the group start date is 1/1 and 1/10 is within the 14 day window from 1/1 (Row 1). Row 3 with date 1/20 is outside of the 14 day window so it belongs to group 2 (series 2) etc.

How can I do this? How can I partition the dates by 14 days and how can I start from a new group based on this rule?

Comment: what about row 2 and row 3?

Comment: Hi there! so Row 3 should be compared to the first row of the previous group (ie. series 1). Row 3 says 1/20 which is greater than 14d + 1/1 so should be assigned to series 2.

Comment: I think that this is going to need some sort of cursor function. What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Okay, you don't want to merely look for rows less than 14 days apart, because that would put rows 2 and 3 in the same group, You want to start with the oldest row. That is Jan 1. You want to include all rows until Jan 13. That makes rows 1 and 2 one group. How to continue then? Next group = Jan 14 to Jan 27? You don't seem to want this, because you include Jan 30 in the second group. So when you are done with the first group, you want to look for the oldest date of the remaining rows and start over from there. This requires a recursive query.

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. Optimally even including the DBMS version. It looks like you need a recursive `WITH` clause based on your rows numbered with the `ROW_NUMBER` function, so you can easily go from row to row in the iteration.

Comment: @Kendle Hi there! I am using SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given your RDBMS.
Here is a solution for mySQL / mariaDB.

> ```
> create table t1 (
> user int,
> view_dt date);
>
> insert into t1 values
> (122,'2022-01-02'),
> (123,'2022-01-01'),
> (123,'2022-01-10'),
> (123,'2022-01-20'),
> (123,'2022-01-25'),
> (123,'2022-01-30'),
> (123,'2022-02-10'),
> (123,'2022-02-15');
> ```

> ```
> SET @gNumber = 0;
> SET @gDate = '1900-01-01';
> set @user = 1;
> SELECT
>   @gNumber := case 
>     when @user = user and datediff(view_dt,@gDate) <= 14 then @gNumber 
>     else @gNumber + 1 end groupNumber,
>   @user := user user,
>   view_dt,
>   @gDate := case when datediff(view_dt,@gDate) <= 14 then @gDate
>     else view_dt end groupDate
> FROM t1 
> ORDER BY 
>   user,
>   view_dt;
> ```

> ```
> groupNumber | user | view_dt    | groupDate 
> ----------: | ---: | :--------- | :---------
>           1 |  122 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02
>           2 |  123 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02
>           2 |  123 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-02
>           3 |  123 | 2022-01-20 | 2022-01-20
>           3 |  123 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-20
>           3 |  123 | 2022-01-30 | 2022-01-20
>           4 |  123 | 2022-02-10 | 2022-02-10
>           4 |  123 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=85e6b16a0d7c4806ca6361445cc53d9e)*